# How is tcgetsid different than getsid function?

Tags: c, api, unix, process, systems-programming

While reading "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment", it appears to me that those two functions do exactly the same thing.

They both return the same result to the calling process.

So why bother design two of them?

---

Thanks larsmans. But if a process wants to know its session id, it can simply do getsid(0), under what circumstance does a process need to call tcgetsid(pid) to know its session id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcgetsid` returns the process group ID of the session for a terminal, denoted by a file descriptor.

`getsid` returns the same for a process, denotes by its PID.

Comment: Thanks larsmans. But if a process wants to know its session id, it can simply do getsid(0), under what circumstance does a process need to call tcgetsid(pid) to know its session id?